# Bash: what delimiter to use for this string to array conversion to work? (Laravel/dotenv/Sail/Docker Compose)

Tags: laravel, bash, laravel-sail, phpdotenv

Laravel Sail should support multiple docker-compose files by configuring them in a dotenv file (`.env`).

The line in my `.env` file...

```
SAIL_FILES='docker-compose.yml:docker-compose-arm.yml'
```

The part of Sail that handles multiple sail files (I can't/shouldn't edit this)

```bash
if [ -n "$SAIL_FILES" ]; then
    # Convert SAIL_FILES to an array...
    SAIL_FILES=("${SAIL_FILES//:/ }")

    for FILE in "${SAIL_FILES[@]}"; do
        if [ -f "$FILE" ]; then
            DOCKER_COMPOSE+=(-f "$FILE")
        else
            echo "${BOLD}Unable to find Docker Compose file: '${FILE}'${NC}" >&2

            exit 1
        fi
    done
fi
```

I've tried a few different delimiters (comma, spaces, .etc). It seems simple but I can't get it to work. I can't understand how `SAIL_FILES=("${SAIL_FILES//:/ }")` performs the array conversion (I'm new to Bash).

I've recreated the issue [here](http://tpcg.io/_COX6OF) which should simply echo each filename on a new line.

This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere on Laravel.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double quoting prevents word-splitting. If you want word-splitting to happen, don't quote:

```
SAIL_FILES=(${SAIL_FILES//:/ })
```

You can also use `$IFS` to split the string without substitution:

```
IFS=: SAIL_FILES=($SAIL_FILES)
```

Comment: That works. I want to avoid editing vendor code. So is this a Laravel Sail issue and my delimiter is fine?

Comment: Does it run in `bash` or some other shell?

Comment: I'm currently on a mac so `zsh`. `ps -p $$` outputs...


`
PID TTY           TIME CMD
15820 ttys005    0:03.64 /bin/zsh --login -i
`

Comment: @mike How do you run the script that contains the code you posted? What shebang line does it start with?

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

Comment: So, if the script is intended to run in bash, it's a bug in the script.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. I'll drop an issue to the guys over at Laravel 